# How do I gather seeds in State of Decay?

Tags: state-of-decay

I've been playing State of Decay and I currently need to gather seeds so I can build a garden.  But I'm at a location that says it should have seeds and I can't find any.  Anyone know what to do?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're tasked with gathering an item during one of these generated side missions, you will usually have multiple buildings that you have to search in order to locate what you're after. Simply search through those buildings until they're empty (and then move on to the next building) or until you find what you're looking for.

Start by searching inside the highlighted region on the map. In your screenshot so far you've only cleared two houses out of the six in the highlighted region so there's still plenty of opportunity to find the seeds you are looking for.